# jQuery mobile and Laravel

Tags: jquery-mobile, laravel-4

I am using Jquery mobile and laravel4.

I have 2 views called "mobilepage1" and "mobilepage2".
On every page there is a "Next"button". A very linear app.

This my controller:

```
public function login(){
             View::share('test','test');  
               return View::make('mobilepages.mobilepage1');         
}
```

On mobilepage1 i do this:

```
{{$test}}
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'mobilepage2', 'method' => 'get')) }}
{{Form:: submit("VERDER")}}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

That goes to mobile page2

On mobilepage2 i also do:

```
{{$test}}
```

This does not seem to work. And gives me the "Error loading page" with the error:

```
{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Undefined variable: test (View: C:\\Google Drive\\htdocs\\laravel4_test4\\app\\views\\mobilepages\\mobilepage2.blade.php)","file":"C:\\Google Drive\\htdocs\\laravel4_test4\\app\\storage\\views\\cdf5614a0a7f85ce1182cff09ad77222","line":17}}
```

If i'm right SHARE is supposed to share in all views like a cookie right? Could it be Jquery mobile is interfering?

---

UPDATE:

I tried turning off ajax on Omars request:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});

</script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
```

The variable still is not shared mobilepage2.

Comment: I dont know about "laravel", maybe jQM is trying to load page via Ajax. try disabling Ajax and see if the page loads correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`$test` variable will be available in all views as long as the `View::share('test','test');` command is executed.

In your case, this command is executed only in the login() method.

If you place:

`View::share('test','test');`

in the top of `routes.php` file you'll see that it will work because this file is executed on every call to your app.

If you don't want to mess your `routes.php` file with view shares or composers, you can do the following:

1. Create a new file (E.g. `composers.php`) inside the app folder (Where routes.php and filters.php live)
2. Open `app/start/global.php` and at the end of the file add

   `require app_path().'/composers.php';`

Now your can place `View::share('test','test');` inside this file and have it available in every call.